# How to grab the last 12 months from cygwin "date" with a static time value

Tags: git, date, github, cygwin

I've got this script

`"$(date +%Y-%m-01) -$i months" +%Y-%m)-01"`

that works great for getting the last 12 months from date, month by month. I want to have a static value for the time being used, so that instead of going back 12 months from the CURRENT TIME it is going back from a static time.

I'm using this with Github and I want to be consistent with the commits I sync to when I want to go back x months.  How to specify time down to the second and use it with this script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use what `git` proves you: `git log --since='X seconds ago'`, e.g. to list all commits in the last year (approximately 365*24*60*60=31536000 seconds)

```
$ git log --since='31536000 seconds ago'
```

You can give an upper bound with `--until`.

If you want to list all commits one year before `SOME_DATE` you can use `date`.

```
# the current time (NOW)
date +%s

# the time a SOME_DATE (e.g. 2011-01-01)
date +%s --date=2011-01-01

# one year before SOME_DATE is
#
#   31536000 + NOW - SOME_DATE
#
# (use bc for calculations)
SECONDS=$(echo 31536000 -  $(date +%s) + $(date +%s --date=2011-01-01) | bc)

# putting it all together:
# display all commits since one year before 2011-01-01 until 2011-01-01
git log --since="$(echo 31536000 + $(date +%s) - $(date +%s --date=2011-01-01)| bc) seconds ago" --before="$(echo $(date +%s) - $(date +%s --date=2011-01-01) | bc -l) seconds ago"
```

Comment: Thanks, this may work but I'm not sure I worded my question well.  I want to be able to go back month by month, on the first day of the month, ON THE FIRST SECOND OF THE MONTH.  or at least from some specified "seconds" value.  I don't want the current time to affect the output of `git log` at all.